# Ruby on Rails: How to create a "recent_search_path" helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a search feature of my application. After submitting a search term, you are redirected to a url that looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?utf8=✓&search=term
```

I want to be able to store this in the session and link to it later:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', recent_search_path %>
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337644/rails-storing-search-query-result/3337715#3337715) answer. Probably what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [rc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49186/rc) for referring me to a very similar question. This could be achieved by storing the current path in the session:

```
session[:recent_search_path] = request.url
```

...and retrieving it again in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Back to search results", session[:recent_search_path] %>
```